# Sorting of two vectors separately?

Tags: c++, vector

I have to make a program which uses the following two vectors:-

```
vector<double> age;
vector<string> name;
```

I take their input separately. I have to make a function sort() such that it sorts name alphabetically and then reorganizes age accordingly to match name.

Please help!!

Comment: I am new to STL and this is my homework.... please don't get angry if it is a stupid question.

Comment: Why don't you `struct` them together? (Or `std::tuple` etc.)

Comment: Also, you may use `std::pair<string, double>` - this will not require you writing comparator manually

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the question says that i have to do it separately. Homework!!!!

Comment: @fleshbender Could you please give more details? I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: @fleshbender You say you need to sort, but what type of sort?  Bubble sort?  Quick sort?  Heap sort?  Merge sort?  Maybe you should start there, which is to determine what sorting algorithm you are supposed to use.  If you don't know, go back to your teacher and ask for more details.

Comment: @fleshbender You plan to use a STL function `sort` or are you required to write a sorting algorithm manually?

Comment: i am using STL function sort() because it says sort name string in alphabetical order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can group them within `struct` or equivalent, you may create an additional vector for indexes that you `sort` and use for indirection:

```
std::vector<double> ages = /**/;
std::vector<string> names = /**/;
// ages.size() == names.size()
std::vector<std::size_t> indexes(names.size());
std::iota(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), 0u);
std::sort(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), [&](std::size_t lhs, std::size_t rhs) {
    return names[lhs] < names[rhs];
});

for (auto index : indexes) {
    std::cout << names[index] << " has " << ages[index] << std::endl;
}
```

And with [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html) you can do:

```
std::vector<double> ages = /**/;
std::vector<string> names = /**/;
auto zip = ranges::view::zip(names, ages);

ranges::sort(zip);

for (const auto& z : zip) {
    std::cout << std::get<0>(z) << " " << std::get<1>(z) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae24da6ed987961c)

Comment: Shouldn't there be a capture mode (either `&` or `=`) for `names` in the lambda function?

Comment: @linuxfever: Yes, fixed.

Comment: By filling new vectors instead of printing out and then moving them to the input vectors, the input vectors are effectively sorted.

Answer (score 3):

If the sort function accepts both the vectors, the easiest way is to copy everything to `std::set<std::pair<string,double>>` which sorts first on name and then copy the sorted entries to the input vectors.  If you can't use sets, you can use vector and sort yourself.

The reason is that sorting changes the order so you lose the link between the entries of both vectors.  If you can't or won't use the combined set method, you need to make sure that the link is maintained in another way, probably via a temporary container with references.

Comment: The set method is the same as the map method given in Trevir's answer.  I just don't think one should give code for homework.  People learn more by coding themselves, even if it's based on tips.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you really need a function that takes two vectors and modifies them.

The sort function can be implemented as:

```
void sort ( vector<double>& ages, vector<string>& names)
{
     if ( ages.size() != names.size() )
         return;

     std::map< string, double > helper_map;
     for ( size_t id = 0; id < names.size(); ++id)
     {
         helper_map.emplace( names[id], ages[id] );
     }

     names.clear();
     ages.clear();

     for (const auto& helper : helper_map)
     {
          names.push_back( helper.first );
          ages.push_back( helper.second );
     } 
}
```

Working example:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2457c832c0b612b2

However keep in mind that this problem should be solved using different approaches as pointed out in the comments. As homework those things don't always apply though.